# Nodejs, trying to export a var to another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

im trying to export a var to another file in a nodejs application, but the result of the export gives me undifined when i try to console.log it.

File im trying to export from, tha arrow line is the var itself

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url');
var userexp


// User Api
router.get('/user/:userid', check_token, (req, res) => {
    var userid = req.params.userid;
    users.getById(userid)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        module.exports.userexp=data <--------------------------------------------------------------------
        io.emit("user",{user:data})
        res.jsonp(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).jsonp(err);
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```

file im tryng to export to

```
var use_test=require('../routes/api')
var socket_io = require('socket.io');
var io       = socket_io();
var socketio = {};
socketio.io  = io;
var users = [];



 io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log(use_test.userexp);
    console.log('A user connected');
    console.log(`Socket connected ${socket.id}`)    
 });




module.exports = socketio;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to a variable, then export the variable, like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url');
var userexp


// User Api
var myRouter = router.get('/user/:userid', check_token, (req, res) => {
    var userid = req.params.userid;
    users.getById(userid)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        module.exports.userexp=data <--------------------------------------------------------------------
        io.emit("user",{user:data})
        res.jsonp(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).jsonp(err);
    });
})

module.exports = myRouter;
```

I might suggest you to use let and const instead of var to declare variables (you can declare functions as const, for example)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: thank for ur time, but this fixed the problem for me,https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/node-js-module-exports-variable-undefined/108331/2